# Linkedin: which partner program for r_network?

Tags: linkedin-api

I saw recently Linkedin restricted access to its api.
The connections (obtained vie the r_network authorization) are no longer available.
I read that if I affiliate to some partner program I may use again the r_network authorization and get users' connections.
I could not find any doc that tells which APIs would be available with a particular partner program.
Does anybody know if there's a partner program that would let me retrieve a users' connections?
Are these partner programs free or do they cost?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for LinkedIn customer service, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I spent hour trying to find this answer and the web and couldnt, neither on the faq. The customer service (which I did contact) said that they do not reply to developer's questions but there's no contact email/form for developers... I posted here hoping that someone who did apply to a partner's program can answer me...

Comment: You need to find somewhere other than StackOverflow to ask that - it's off-topic here.

Comment: That is strange... as stated in the linkedin developer support page (https://developer.linkedin.com/support):
"We collaborate on questions tagged "linkedin" at Stack Overflow. Leverage the power of the best support community on the internet to get the answers to your LinkedIn API programming questions."...

Comment: Unfortunately they haven't bothered to figure out what's allowed at StackOverflow before saying that.